# Issues parsing a log file in the PowerShell pipeline

Tags: powershell, wget

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://192.168.100.1/cgi-bin/status_cgi','C:\file.txt')
```

retrieves the status page from an Arris Modem.

```
select-string -Path "C:\file.txt" -pattern "Uptime"
```

yields:

```
C:\file.txt:96:<tbody><tr><td width="160">System Uptime: </td><td>0 d: 18 h: 33  m</td></tr>
```

as expected, but

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).Downloadstring('http://192.168.100.1/cgi-bin/status_cgi') | select-string -pattern 'Uptime'
```

prints the entire page and doesn't select the string.

Requesting stream output from Webclient also won't "pipe"

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).openread('http://192.168.100.1/cgi-bin/status_cgi') | select-string -pattern 'Uptime'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You my have to split the returned string with the `-split` operator --> `(new-object System.Net.WebClient).openread('http://192.168.100.1/cgi-bin/status_cgi') -split "`r?`n" | select-string -pattern 'Uptime'`

Answer (score -1):

When you pipe the output of `System.Net.WebClient` to **Select-String**, the output is treated as one string, that is why the output is matched as a whole.

When you save the output of `System.Net.WebClient` to a file and then read it using `Select-String -Path path/to/the/file`, **Select-String** treats the content of file as array of lines, and returns only lines matched by the pattern.

FYI: In Powershell 3+ it is more convenient to use **Invoke-WebRequest** cmdlet:

```
$uri = 'http://192.168.100.1/cgi-bin/status_cgi'
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri).Content -split "`n" |
    Select-String -SimpleMatch Uptime
```

References:

- [WebClient.DownloadString Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns single string